# Send parameter to before_save

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to build an app in the "rails way", so this time instead of retrospectively processing records in the database, I am trying to do them using a before_save method, namely this one:

```
 def make_percentage_from(score)
   percent = (score.fdiv(20) * 100)
   return percent
 end
```

Every item that comes into the database has a score out of 20, before it gets saved to the database I would like to store this as a percentage, however the issue I am having is that I am unable to send any attribute data via a before_save.

Ideally I'd have

before_save :make_percentage_from(score-to-be-calculated)

How can I do this? Google isn't turning up so much for me and I'm determined not to have to process this data once its stored (providing of course there *is* another way!)

Thanks and regards

Geoff

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `score` and `percentage` are attributes of `Widget`:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validates :calculate_score_percentage
  validates :percentage, :presence => true
private
  def calculate_score_percentage
    self.percentage = score.fdiv(20) * 100
  end
end
```

This works because all of your attributes/columns have getter and setter methods automatically defined by ActiveRecord. The reference to `score` in the `calculate_score_percentage` method is actually calling the `self.score` method, which will return the `score` object/value. We have to use `self.percentage` explicitly because it would be ambiguous to use `percent` alone — it could be either defining a local `percentage` variable, or calling `self.percentage=`. The default would be the former, which is not what we want in this case.

I'm using `before_validates` to show that you can use validation still here, which is good for some sanity checking. If you didn't want to do any validation, you could swap it out for `before_save` without any code changes.

Comment: Excellent, thorough response.

Answer (score 11):

The short answer: callbacks never have parameters. It is assumed that callbacks take action on the object or record itself. So anything that you would need as a parameter you would need to store either as an attribute (which is saved to the database) or as an instance variable.