# rails - collecting data (no Active Record) from form submitted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, forms, parameters, before-save

EDIT: Rephrase my question:

I have a `@template_written` from which I generate the `@final_written.body`. Therefore, to create the `@final_written`, the `@final_written.body` is prefilled(`final_written belongs_to template_written`).

From the `@final_written.body`, the array `@names (attr_accessor :names)` is generated with texts surrounded with @@.

```
@names = ["Lorem ipsum", "aliquip ex ea", "cillum dolore", "est laborum"]
```

My goal is replace the array occurrences in the `@final_written.body` with a form (in the view 'new').

I added this in a form (in new.html.erb):

```
<%= @names.each do |k| %> 
    <%=  label_tag k %> <br>
    <%=  text_field_tag k %> <br>
<% end %>
```

which send this:

```
  Parameters: 
  {
   "utf8"=>"✓", 

   "authenticity_token"=>"iw3ZCksupersecretU4sVyi5D",

   "final_written"=>{
              "title"=>"Ted", 
              "body"=>"@@Lorem ipsum@@ dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut @@aliquip ex ea@@ commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse @@cillum dolore@@ eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id @@est laborum@@."
              }, 

    "Lorem ipsum"=>"bla", 
    "aliquip ex ea"=>"bla", 
    "cillum dolore"=>"bla", 
    "est laborum"=>"bla", 

     "commit"=>"Create final_written", 
     "template_written_id"=>"1"
  }
```

I tried with (and thousands of other things), but don't work (comment.rb):

```
 before_save :change 

  protected

    def change
        kwords = self.body.scan(/@@(.+?)@@/).flatten
        kwords = kwords.uniq
        cuerpo = self.body

        kwords.each do |i| 
             i = params[:i]
             cuerpo.gsub(/@@#{i}@@/, i)
        end

        self.body = cuerpo

    end
```

**How to collect the data who i need from the submitted data? and
How to use it to modify the `@final_written.body` before save?**

Thanks alot guys! I need to understand how this works!

**EDIT**

I read in [Send parameter to before_save](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8096137/send-parameter-to-before-save)

> The short answer: callbacks never have parameters. It is assumed that callbacks take action on the object or record itself. So anything that you would need as a parameter you would need to store either as an attribute (which is saved to the database) or as an instance variable. @nathanvda

As @Mattherick says:

> the params are available in the controller, but not in the model. you
>   could pass them to a method in your model, but params[:i] would not
>   work in the model..

How to resolve this problem?

Comment: What do you exactly want to realize? :-) I do not really get your question, sorry. But what I can see so far is that you do something with params[:i] in your model..that will not work.. the params are available in the controller, but not in the model. you could pass them to a method in your model, but params[:i] would not work in the model..

Comment: @Mattherick I need the value of the keys "Lorem ipsum", "aliquip ex ea", "cillum dolore" and "est laborum", those pairs are no active record data, and I need it to execute a before_save class.

Comment: Why are you using `before_save`? As you said, you are not dealing with `AR` objects. Can't you simply use a method that accept parameters from your controller do your thing and return the modified text to the controller?

Comment: @MurifoX Well, I don't know how do it... any clues?

Answer (score 0):

1) I do not really understand your logic, and why you should do that, but anyway, maybe I could help you.. :-)

2) You should change your form, that you have a "container"-params around your "on-the-fly" generated form fields..

```
<%= @name.each do |k| %> 
  <%= label_tag k %> <br>
  <%= text_field_tag "your_container[#{k}]" %> <br/>
<% end %>
```

This will change your parameter to following:

```
Parameters: 
  {
  "utf8"=>"✓", 
  "authenticity_token"=>"iw3ZCksupersecretU4sVyi5D",
  "comment"=>{
    "commenter"=>"Ted", 
    "body"=>"@@Lorem ipsum@@ dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut @@aliquip ex ea@@ commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse @@cillum dolore@@ eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id @@est laborum@@."
   }, 

"your_container"=>{
  "Lorem ipsum"=>"bla",
  "aliquip ex ea"=>"bla",
  "cillum dolore"=>"bla",
  "est laborum"=>"bla"
},

 "commit"=>"Create Comment", 
 "post_id"=>"1"
}
```

3) Change your controller action to something like following:

comment_controller.rb (Rails 4.2):

```
def create
  @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
  if @comment.save
   redirect_to your_path
  else
   render :new
  end
end

private

  def comment_params
    params[:comment][:body] = Comment.extract_body(params[:comment][:body], params[:your_container])
    params.require(:comment).permit(:commenter, :body, :post_id)
  end
```

comment.rb

```
def self.extract_body(body, hash)
  kwords = body.scan(/@@(.+?)@@/).flatten
  kwords = kwords.uniq

  kwords.each do |i|
    body = body.gsub(/@@#{i}@@/, hash[i])
  end

  body
end
```

I really do not know if this is the result you want to have.. and I did not test my code..but maybe this approach could help you..

Comment: Thanks for response. Don't result, I get `NoMethodError in CommentsController#create
undefined method [] for nil:NilClass

Extracted source (around line #21):
#21      body = body.gsub(/@@#{i}@@/, hash[i])`
. And the conteiner don't change the form submit params :(

Comment: the idea is to create templates whose forms change the variable text, which is surrounded by '@@'

Comment: can you post your new params hash, pls?